# Adding Style to Specific Popover in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at this Demo and let me know how I can add style ONLY to `#pop-one` and not to all of the popovers?

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pop-one">Pop 1 </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="pop-two">Pop 2 </button>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#pop-one").popover({
         placement: function() { return $(window).width() < 975 ? 'bottom' : 'right'; },
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="" style=""><strong>Pop One</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-default close"\
     onclick="$("#pop-captcha").popover("hide");">x</button>',
        content : '<h4>This is Pop One</h4>',
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    var popup = $(this);
    $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
      popup.click();
    });
  }); 


$("#pop-two").popover({
         placement: function() { return $(window).width() < 975 ? 'bottom' : 'right'; },
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="" style=""><strong>Pop Two</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-default close"\
     onclick="$("#pop-captcha").popover("hide");">x</button>',
               content : '<h4>This is Pop Two</h4>',
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    var popup = $(this);
    $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
      popup.click();
    });
  });
```

I already tried this:

```
#pop-one .popover .popover-content{background:red;}
```

but id didn't do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css syntax was not working due to the relationship the button(#pop-one) and div(.popover) elements share. They are siblings, not parent-child.

You could use adjacent selectors in this case, following the syntax `E1 + E2`. This rule applies when both E1 and E2 share the same parent and E2 element immediately follows E1 element.

```
#pop-one + .popover .popover-content{background:red;}

#pop-two + .popover {background:green;}
```

Check [fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obGZMw).